# Getting Value for table_id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables SaleMaster

```cs
public class SaleMaster
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Installments> Installments { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Installments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Month { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get the all the Installments with pending due dates,
but I also want to include the SaleMaster ID from Installment table so I can navigate back.

```cs
List<Installments> instalment = con.DbSetInstallments
    .Where(x => x.Month < d && x.IsPaid == false)
    .ToList();
```

Now I want to take SaleMaster from this list of which Installments are due.

Comment: Where is the MVC relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a relational property to `SaleMaster` in `Installments`:

```
public class Installments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Month { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }

    public int SaleMasterId { get; set; }
    public virtual SaleMaster SaleMaster { get; set; }
}
```

This way you have easy access to the SaleMaster's `Id`.